# Google Cloud / Firebase Functions, handling dependencies per function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

We have a couple of functions that require a lot of dependencies to work. We have so called jar/npm/lib hell going on, and would like to limit the dependencies on function, rather than on project level. Is this possible?

Edit: trying to rephrase the question as Doug instructed: We're using Firebase functions and we'd like to isolate the function's dependencies from other function's dependencies. We need version x.y.z of dependency A for function 1 to work, but function 2 needs version f.y.z of the same dependency A to work.

I suspect that the only way around this is to deploy it to another project, but wanted to ask a question here before committing to that.

So, can we have multiple versions of the same dependency in one Firebase Functions deployment?

Edit 2: Divided the other part of the question here: [Firebase Functions: is it OK to divide functions to multiple projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45561586/firebase-functions-is-it-ok-to-divide-functions-to-multiple-projects)

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding exactly what you're trying to do.  Also, it sounds like you're asking two different questions here.  I think it would be better if you ask the different questions separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no, one can't control the dependencies per function, but per deployment. This is more of a limitation of npm itself than Firebase / Google Cloud Functions.