# Firebase Functions: is it OK to divide functions to multiple projects

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

This is in relation to the question here: [Google Cloud / Firebase Functions, handling dependencies per function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45543216/google-cloud-firebase-functions-handling-dependencies-per-function)

So, to manage dependencies better, is it allowed to divide the functions to as many projects as we see fit?

This would create one "master" project, that contains the data in database and storage + the projects that are otherwise empty, but contain only certain functions.

Thins of the following projects: My Awesome App, My Awesome App Stats Api, My Awesome App Admin Api etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what kinds of functions you're writing.

If you want to write database triggers, they have to be in the same project as the database that's receiving the writes.  You can't have a second project respond to writes from the database in the first project.

If you want to write HTTP triggers, you can init the admin SDK to point to different projects for querying and such.

I don't particularly see any need to "shard" your functions like this in a production environment.  Cloud Functions will scale your functions as needed to handle the load, and having different functions in different projects shouldn't make a difference in that respect.

Comment: I'm not worried about performance, the reason for the split is given in the linked question.

 Quote: "If you want to write HTTP triggers, you can init the admin SDK to point to different projects for querying and such." This is exactly what I planned to do, but am unsure if it is OK for Firebase to do so, as it would make us run in the free tier, as the invocation counts would be lower. (When calculating per project counts.)

Comment: You're free to try that.  Note that each project will have different host names for the functions they host.